# How to use Base64 image with Itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, pdf, base64, itext, uri

In this code snippet, which I using for converting HTML into PDF and then convert back to the `MemoryStream`.

```
private MemoryStream createPDF(string html)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);

        HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);

        document.Open();
        worker.StartDocument();

        worker.Parse(reader); //error occurs in here
        
        worker.EndDocument();
        worker.Close();
        document.Close();
        var bytedata = msOutput.ToArray();
        var pdfContent = new MemoryStream(bytedata);
        return pdfContent;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

But when the HTML content consists with the Base64 image. I'm getting this error in this line (`worker.Parse(reader);`).

```
The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

I did several workaround, and got to know this occurs because that the URI that can interpret `itextsharp` must be without the data prefix. How can I solve this?

Comment: Ho, any reason on using iText 5? Have you tried iText 7's pdfHTML add-on?

Comment: Can you attach the HTML reproducing the problem? I guess the best solution is to move to iText 7 pdfHTML, and if you want to stay with iText 5 then preprocess your HTML to convert images into the format that itextsharp accepts. You can also look into customizing the workers etc but it's difficult in itextsharp

Answer (score 4):

Hello I have implemented a small management of the image in base64 (to me comes from an html upload so I also removed the tags). I report the solution while knowing that you will have solved (given the past time) but at least if others have the same question they will have a starting input

**VB CODE**

```
    Dim myText As String = dictionary.Item("@template.testo").ToString()
    Dim phrase As String = "<img src=""data:image/png;base64,"
    Dim phrase2 As String = """ alt="""">"
    Dim Occurrences As Integer = (myText.Length - myText.Replace(phrase, String.Empty).Length) / phrase.Length

    For value As Integer = 0 To Occurrences
        Dim immagineBase64 As String = myText.Substring(myText.IndexOf(phrase), myText.IndexOf(phrase2) - (phrase2.Length + 2)).Replace(phrase, "").Replace(phrase2, "")
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(immagineBase64)
        Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes)

        documento.Add(image)

        myText = myText.Replace(myText.Substring(myText.IndexOf(phrase), myText.IndexOf(phrase2) - (phrase2.Length + 2)), "")
    Next
```

**C# CODE**

```
        string myText = dictionary.Item("@template.testo").ToString()   // my base64 image with html tag
        string phrase = "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,"
        string phrase2 = "\" alt=\"\">"
        int Occurrences = (myText.Length - myText.Replace(phrase, String.Empty).Length) / phrase.Length

        for(int value = 0; value < Occurrences; value++){
            string immagineBase64 = myText.Substring(myText.IndexOf(phrase), myText.IndexOf(phrase2) - (phrase2.Length + 2)).Replace(phrase, "").Replace(phrase2, "")
            Byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(immagineBase64)
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes)

            documento.Add(image)
        }
```

Hope it helps